# What is the name of the Salesforce mascot that looks like a leopard/cat version of Astro?

Tags: trailhead

This is totally a non-technical question. But I'm trying to search more about this mascot. I've seen it as a small icon on the Trailblazer Community I think, where your profile picture would go if you were logged in.

The mascot looks like a female version of Astro (the boy with racoon outfit), but the costume is different, it looks more like a leopard/cat, and she uses glasses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be Appy. Below is a link to all the mascots.

https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/07/meet-trailhead-characters.html

Comment: Believe it or not, I've visited that page before asking here, but her image didn't load at first. :P Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I always wanted to know their names and this gave me a chance to look it up for myself.